# How to fix Type Error cannot read property 'cityName' of undefined in the weather forecast project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I had seen every syntax but I could see any type of error in my project. Can you help me where is the problem really is?

I wanted to make a weather project by the api but when I load the code in the browser it is showing the type error "cityName" but I don't see any error in there.can you help me out where is the problem is I give a pic also.

HTML file

```
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Weather Forcast</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <label for="cityInput">City Name:</label>
                <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="cityName">
                <button type="submit">Go</button>
            </form>        
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript file

```
    const express= require("express");
    const https = require("https");
    const app = express();
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    
    });
    
    app.post("/", function(req, res){ 
        const query =req.body.cityName;
        const apiKey ="e3e24d2fb12aafc8d8bf05b91d5f0ae0";
        const unit ="metric";
        const url ="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + unit;
    
        https.get(url, function(response){
            console.log(response.statusCode);
    
            response.on("data", function(data){
                const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
                const temp = weatherData.main.temp
                const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description
                res.write("<p>The weather is currently" + weatherDescription + "</p>");
                res.write("<h1>The tempreature in "+ query +" is " + temp +"degress Celcius.</h1>")
                res.send();
                
            })
       })
    });
    
    
    
    
       app.listen(3000, function(){
           console.log("Server is running on Port 3000");
       })
```

[The error I got from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxAYq.png)

Comment: You need to have body-parsing middleware to populate req.body. add `app.use(express.json()) ` next to `const app=express()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not installed `body-parser` which parse the incoming request and you are using `req.body.cityName` which javascript would not understand.

So, refer this link [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)
and refer to the following code.

```
//jsonhint express versio:6.0
  const express= require("express");
  const https = require("https");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const app = express();
  

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
  }));

  app.get("/", function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  
  });
  
  app.post("/", function(req, res){ 
      const query =req.body.cityName;
      const apiKey ="e3e24d2fb12aafc8d8bf05b91d5f0ae0";
      const unit ="metric";
      const url ="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + unit;
  
      https.get(url, function(response){
          console.log(response.statusCode);
  
          response.on("data", function(data){
              const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
              const temp = weatherData.main.temp
              const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description
              res.write("<p>The weather is currently" + weatherDescription + "</p>");
              res.write("<h1>The tempreature in "+ query +" is " + temp +"degress Celcius.</h1>")
              res.send();
              
          })
     })
  });
  
  
  
  
     app.listen(3000, function(){
         console.log("Server is running on Port 3000");
     })
```

Comment: I have a question, why did you give extended as a false in the code I mention ? app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
  }));

Comment: bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}) - middleware for parsing bodies from URL. Options can be [found here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions). Source code can be [found here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/56a2b73c26b2238bc3050ad90af9ab9c62f4eb97/lib/types/urlencoded.js#L43).

Answer (score 0):

Look like you haven't use bodyParser yet, so req.body will be undefined.

Try add bodyParser to your JavaScript file to see if it work

```
const express= require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the `request` body before performing any kind of operation. You can use `express.json()` middleware function to parse the request body. 
**For more information visit [Express Official Documentaion](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)**

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Final code:

```
const express= require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

// Middleware function to parse the request body;
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

});

app.post("/", function(req, res){ 
    const query =req.body.cityName;
    const apiKey ="e3e24d2fb12aafc8d8bf05b91d5f0ae0";
    const unit ="metric";
    const url ="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + unit;

    https.get(url, function(response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data", function(data){
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp
            const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description
            res.write("<p>The weather is currently" + weatherDescription + "</p>");
            res.write("<h1>The tempreature in "+ query +" is " + temp +"degress Celcius.</h1>")
            res.send();
            
        })
   })
});




   app.listen(3000, function(){
       console.log("Server is running on Port 3000");
   })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the, answer you told me didn't work. Later answer told me that I didn't install the body-parser package after installing and adding the code it started to work properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of express are you using?

Comment: I am using express version 6

Comment: Express current stable version is 4.17.1 and latest alpha is 5.0.0-alpha.8
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express?activeTab=versions

Comment: sorry, I should told that jshint esversion:6